# Какие C++ компиляторы имеют текущую актуальную версию и каков уровень поддержки ими стандарта?

Tags: c++builder, visual-c++, c++

Вот ясно, что gcc, microsoft visual c++, embarcadero c++ builder развиваются и выходят новые версии. Очень печально, но Comeau похоже находится в коме (последняя версия аж 4.3.10.1 beta2 / October 6, 2008). Но вот какова ситуация с остальными? Про тот же Ватком я уже давно не слышал, практически с тех пор, как он стал OpenWatcom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Активно развивается Intel Compiler. Watcom, судя по всему, не развивается, а жалко. В качестве альтернативы gcc очень быстро растёт Clang/LLVM с рядом продвинутых фич. На [странице Страуструпа](http://www.stroustrup.com/compilers.html) упоминаются ещё несколько, но они, похоже, вне мэйнстрима.

GCC и Clang хорошо поддерживают C++11 (пока не полностью, но работа идёт активно, Clang немного впереди). Microsoft Visual C++ медленнее, VS 2010 пока не очень хорошо поддерживает новый стандарт (не знаю, как в 2012).

С другими компиляторами на десктопе не встречался; для embedded есть своё семейство (обычно обрезанный по функциональности язык, без исключений и сложных шаблонных наворотов), но тут я не специалист.

Answer (score 6):

[Сравнительная таблица](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=118165827)

[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

[CLang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

[VC++](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Таблица, такое ощущение, малость устарела. Про последние билдеры (embarcadero c++ builder xe3) в ней информации нет.

Comment: last edited 2012-11-03 17:40:22
Билдер никогда не славился хорошей поддержкой стандарта

Answer (score 5):

Про MS VC++ могу добавить, что начиная с 11 версии студии, MS решили серьёзно взяться за регулярные обновления компилятора с всё большим количеством поддерживаемых фич из С++11.
Вот интересный [пост](http://habrahabr.ru/post/157239/) на Хабре, в котором есть ссылка на последнее обновление компилятора.
Ну это, если кому интересно :)

Answer (score 4):

Одна из наиболее полных и обновляемых таблиц находится на [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).