# Поддержка компиляторами C++17

Tags: c++, компилятор, c++17

Знаю, что некоторые компиляторы вводят экспериментальные фичи новых стандартов ещё до того, как они полностью утверждены. Пример — модули в Visual Studio (сам не щупал, но читал и видел). Да, именно те самые модули из C++17, которые должны были заменить жуткие препроцессорные include-ы. Кстати, их вроде решили пока не вводить :(

Вопрос в следующем: где можно почитать, какие фичи и где уже введены в тестовом режиме? Хотелось бы почитать структурированную информацию. В частности интересует компилятор MS и g++. А ещё точнее, волнует судьба **static if**/**constexpr if** (привет с моих прошлых вопросов). Баги, кроссплатформенность и стабильность не особо важны, просто хочется попробовать новое своими руками.

P.S. Можно уже создать метку c++17

Comment: Метка `c++17` создана.

Comment: [Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#cpp17table)

Comment: Последняя студия не поддерживает полностью даже `C++14`? Вот это новость.

Comment: А ещё http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485216/10105

Comment: Хорошая таблица, спасибо. Но всё же нигде не описаны экспериментальные расширения компилятора (той же студии)

Comment: `static if` нет даже в проекте, Вы о чём?

Comment: @ixSci в проекте нет, но он был предложен (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0128r0.html). Не знаю, насколько это официальный документ и как близок он к осуществлению, но на хабре и в различных блогах иногда мелькает фраза "compile-time if уже обсуждается".

Comment: Кажется, вот список расширений языка в MSVC++: [Microsoft Extensions to C and C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8.aspx) + все [ключевые слова](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e6a4at9.aspx) с `__` в начале.

Comment: @VladD кажется, **__if_exists** - это то, что мне нужно. Спасибо, очень полезная информация!

Comment: Когда я смотрел в последний раз, впереди планеты всей по фичам был `clang`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К упомянутым в комментариях могу добавить с хабра https://habrahabr.ru/post/111691/
Особенно стоит глянуть на ссылки в комментариях.
И еще можно послушать эпизод CppCast
Effective C++
http://cppcast.com/2015/09/scott-meyers/
Тут больше про C++11/14 но возможные будущие фичи также упоминаются.
Кстати, скоро в команде разработчиков новых стандартов C++ появится россиянин, вроде из яндекса, поэтому возможно они что-то публиковать будут.